# How to use the useBulkCopyForBatchInsert on the JdbcSinkConnector?

Tags: apache-kafka

I’m trying to bulk insert to the mssql db table by adding “useBulkCopyForBatchInsert=true” to the connection.url option of Jdbcsinkconnector as below.

"connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://***.***.**.**:1433;database=****;useBulkCopyForBatchInsert=true"

But data is not being inserted using bulk insert.
I will attach the connect log and reference document.

- Using bulk copy API for batch insert operation
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver16
- Connect Log

  [2022-07-18 16:46:32,224] INFO JdbcSinkConfig values:
  auto.create = false
  auto.evolve = false
  batch.size = 3000
  connection.attempts = 3
  connection.backoff.ms = 10000
  connection.password = [hidden]
  connection.url = jdbc:sqlserver://***.**.***.**:1433;database=****;useBulkCopyForBatchInsert=true
  connection.user = ****
  db.timezone = Asia/Seoul
  delete.enabled = false
  dialect.name =
  fields.whitelist = []
  insert.mode = insert
  max.retries = 10
  pk.fields = []
  pk.mode = none
  quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS
  retry.backoff.ms = 3000
  table.name.format = ****
  table.types = [TABLE]
  (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkConfig:361)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but you're using the wrong JDBC URL for SQL Server. You should use `jdbc:sqlserver://...:1433;databaseName=;` instead of `jdbc:sqlserver://...:1433;database=;`.